# Auto it how to check if window appears and close

Tags: window, autoit

How do I check if a specific windoww appears in Autoit.

At the moment I am running with Auto it Adobe After Effect,
so far so good.

The problem is that a warning message pops up if the user does not have quick time installed.

Now I want to check if that window appears and is active and then close it.

So far I have this but did not work:

```
    Local $iPID = Run("C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects CC 2015\Support Files\AfterFX.exe", "", @SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)

    WinWait("[CLASS:AfterEffects]", "", 1000)

    Sleep(200000)

   ; if qicktime warning eror appears
   If WinExists ("DroverLord - Window Class", "") Then
      Send ("{ENTER}")
   EndIf
```

Comment: Have a look at the OPT ( AutoItSetOption) commands. Then first start to get the handle of the window or use title and text instead. After that use a loop to check whether the window exsits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an some example code of what you are trying to do:

```
Local $fDiff
Local $sAfterFXPath = "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects CC 2015\Support Files\AfterFX.exe"

If FileExists($sAfterFXPath) Then
    Local $iPID = Run($sAfterFXPath, "", @SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)

;no need to call WinExists becuase you are waiting for it to exist and be active with WinActivate

Local $hTimer = TimerInit() ; Begin the timer and store the handle in a variable.

Do
    $fDiff = TimerDiff($hTimer)
Until WinActive("Title you are looking for") Or $fDiff >= 30000 ;<<<will exit loop when the window is active or after 30 seconds

If WinActive("Title you are looking for") Then
    ;Closes the window now that it is active
    WinClose("Title you are looking for")
Else
    MsgBox(0, "", "The window was never active.")
EndIf
Else
   MsgBox(0, "", "File path not found. Do something else...")
EndIf
```

Comment: This seems to work so far thank you, do you also know why my code did not work?

Comment: I got a second window which appears after this do you know how to close that? I tried this but did not work   If WinActivate("Welcome to Adobe After Effects") Then
   WinClose("Welcome to Adobe After Effects")
   EndIf

Comment: I have not tested your code but it looks like "Sleep(200000)" could have been the problem. That is pausing the script for 200 seconds.

Comment: This will wait up to 30 seconds for the window and close it if it comes up: ['code'] If WinWait("Welcome to Adobe After Effects", "", 30) Then WinClose("Welcome to Adobe After Effects")

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?

```
Opt("WinDetectHiddenText", 1) ;0=don't detect, 1=do detect
Opt("WinSearchChildren", 1) ;0=no, 1=search children also
Opt("WinTextMatchMode", 1) ;1=complete, 2=quick
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2) ;1=start, 2=subStr, 3=exact, 4=advanced, -1 to -4=Nocase

#include<Date.au3>

Local $iPID = Run("C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects CC 2015\Support Files\AfterFX.exe", "", @SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)
If @error Then
    ConsoleWrite('ERROR' & @CRLF)
    Exit(0)
EndIf

Global $end = False
Do
    ; if qicktime warning eror appears
    If WinExists("DroverLord - Window Class", "") Then
        ConsoleWrite('!FOUND ' & _NowTime() & @CRLF)
        Send("{ENTER}") ;close?
        WinClose("DroverLord - Window Class", "") ; this
        WinKill("DroverLord - Window Class", "") ; or this
        $end = True
    EndIf
Until $end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunaly it did not work.

Comment: Did you check if the title is correct? Did the windows found message show up in the Scite console?